# prevent RTK Query api request until user complete the form

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have this code that works fine:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import 'flatpickr/dist/themes/dark.css';
import 'nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setPageTitle } from '../../store/themeConfigSlice';
import { setYearCountrySelection } from '../../store/counterSlice';
import { useAllDataQuery } from '@/store/features/mainApiSlice';

const YearCountrySelect = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    year: 2023,
    country: 'SPA',
});
const { data, isFetching } = useAllDataQuery({ year: formData.year, country: formData.country });

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        dispatch(setYearCountrySelection(data));
    }
}, [data]);


return (
    <form className="panel">
        <div className="mb-2 flex items-center justify-between"></div>
        <div>
            <select onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, year: e.target.value })} className="form-select mb-3 text-white-dark">
                {Array.from({ length: 11 }, (_, i) => 2023 - i).map((item) => (
                    <option key={item} value={item}>
                        {item}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <select onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, country: e.target.value })} className="form-select mb-3 text-white-dark">
                <option value={'SPA'}>Spain</option>
                <option value={'FRA'}>France</option>
                <option value={'ITA'}>Italy</option>
                <option value={'GER'}>Germany</option>
                <option value={'NED'}>Holland</option>
                <option value={'BEL'}>Belgium</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-1 flex justify-end">
            {' '}
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1">
                {allDataIsLoading ? (
                    <div className="px-2">
                        <span class="m-auto inline-block h-5 w-5 animate-spin rounded-full border-2 border-primary border-l-transparent  align-middle"></span>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    'Select'
                )}
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
);
};

export default YearCountrySelect;
```

The problem is that every time user changes the form to select year or country, the hook useAllDataQuery makes a request to the API, I want the hook waits until the form is complete and then request to API using onSubmit or onClick in the button

Answer (score 0):

Solved using useLazyQuery hook insted of useQuery hook:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery